# Isometric Tile maps in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, isometric, tilemap, cocos2d-x

Is there an specific isometric tile map handler in cocos2d-x? I can't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CCTMXTiledMap: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/da/d68/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_t_m_x_tiled_map.html

It supports isometric, hexagonal and orthogonal tiles.